# Celery Beat unable to find database models (django.db.utils.OperationalError)

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have to add few periodic tasks. I'm using Celery - Redis in Django platform. 
When I execute the method from shell_plus all is well . However Celery Beat is unable to find the database instance properly.

Celery version = 4.1.0. I had previously installed django-celery-beats etc 
Database = MySQL

Where am i wrong.

Thanks in advance.
Celery Command

```
(venv)$:/data/project/(sesh/dev)$ celery -A freightquotes worker -B -E -l INFO --autoscale=2,1
```

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 604800}

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL

CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = datetime.timedelta(days=1)  # Take note of the CleanUp task in middleware/tasks.py
CELERY_MAX_CACHED_RESULTS = 1000
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

REDIS_CONNECT_RETRY = True
REDIS_DB = 0
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 2
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 600

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test': {
            'task': 'loads.tasks.test',
            'schedule':  crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
```

**init.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**celery.py**

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings.base')

app = Celery('project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**loads/tasks.py**

```
@task()
def test():
    x = [i.id for i in Load.objects.all()]
    print (x)
```

**Error**

```
[2017-11-30 03:52:00,032: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task loads.tasks.test[0020e4ae-5e52-49d8-863f-e51c2acfd7a7] raised unexpected: OperationalError('no such table: loads_load',)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: loads_load

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/loads/tasks.py", line 146, in test
    x = [i.id for i in Load.objects.all()]
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1103, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 886, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 876, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: loads_load
```

Comment: Whats in __init__.py file?

Comment: just updated. sorry i missed it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some answer.

We have few files in settings like base, dev, prod and local. The database settings is different in each one of them.

Its working when i point the celery app to the local which has all database config. In this case i had to copy all celery config from base to local.

I tried to use django.conf.settings as os.environ.setdefault , but didnt work.

So the answer is incorrect configuration. if we have all in one file we are fine. if we split we have to find some work around.

### Edit

Since the issue was finding the right settings file. I now start the celery by setting the module 
`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='project.settings.dev' celery -A project worker -B -E -l INFO --autoscale=2,1`